# How to get user's access token and access token secret when logging in twitter with TwitterAuthProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Here's the code I am using as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth?hl=en&authuser=0#twitter):

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<void> _signInWithTwitter() async {
  TwitterAuthProvider twitterProvider = TwitterAuthProvider();

  if (kIsWeb) {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(twitterProvider);
  } else {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(twitterProvider);
  }
}
```

This code is successfully logging me into twitter but I am unable to get the user's `access token` and `access token secret`.